# PUT or DELETE verb in ASP.NET MVC on HTML form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, forms, http-put

I have a simple user registration form, with two fields, one for username and another for the password. I have a controller called `UserController` which has these two actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Register(string username, string password)
{
    // Registering user
    return View();
}
```

I used **HTTP Put** to make my website RESTful (PUT verb for insertion). However, when I submit my form, I get 404 error. Here is my form's HTML:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("Register", "User")' method="post">
<div class='field'>
    <label for='username'>
        Username:
    </label>
    <input type='text' id='username' name='username' maxlength='100' />
</div>
<div class='field'>
    <label for='password'>
        Password:
    </label>
    <input type='password' id='password' name='password' maxlength='50' />
</div>
</form>
```

What do I miss here? What's wrong?

Comment: did you considered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: Good post @FosterZ, thanks. However, I'm looking for the workaround implementation in ASP.NET MVC. Do you know how can I implement that?

Answer (score 27):

Since no one really answered it here, I'll add my .02

MVC adds the following field to the html form (used for example when using Html.BeginForm()) to support this. 
Even though HttpPut and HttpDelete are not actually supported for Html5 (they were at one point and then removed from the draft specification), the server libs for MVC will properly route the request to your HttpDelete or HttpPut method when the following form field is posted with your HttpPost request:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeAction"){ 
   @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

HTML forms (up to HTML version 4 and XHTML 1) only support GET and POST as HTTP request methods. XHTML 2.0 will support GET, POST, PUT and DELETE for forms.

A workaround for this for methods through POST by using a hidden form field which is read by the server and dispatch accordingly.

For now, you may consider using `[HttpPost]` now or use `XmlHttpRequest` to use `Put` verb on your request.

---

### UPDATE

You may use `SimplyRestfulRouteHandler` from [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)

It quite simple, register this on `RegisterRoutes`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     SimplyRestfulRouteHandler.BuildRoutes(routes);
}
```

Add a `hidden` field like this with name `_method` inside your `form`

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

This would be good to go.

Comment: But I know that ASP.NET supports HTTP Put out of the box. How can I make ASP.NET MVC set a hidden field in my form and dispatch the submitted (posted) form to my proper method, which has `[HttpPut]` attribute?

Comment: ASP.Net supports it out of the box, yes, but it's the *browser* that you need to pay attention to.  Just because your server-side code recognizes the PUT verb doesn't mean the client does.  Browsers submitting HTML forms only support GET and POST.

Answer (score 4):

You could use $.ajax to submit the form with the correct verb

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cdbTq/2/) is an example