# MVC 3 project - The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, jsonresult, maproute

I'm having problem with MVC 3 routing. I have this function in the Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("Invitations",
                        "api/invitations",
                        new { controller = "Invitations", action = "Invitation" });
```

And i have a Controller:

```
public class InvitationsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPut]
    public JsonResult Invitation(InvitationResponse invitationResponse)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

The problem is that i'm get the error `NotFound or The resource cannot be found`. Can anyone see the problem?

EDIT: The URL im using is "http://localhost:6055/API/Invitations"

Comment: Could you post the route using in your browser

Comment: So your javascript code is `PUT`ing a `InvitationResponse` to that url and you're getting the `NotFound` error?

Comment: can you post the URI you are using to access the resource?

Comment: The URL is "http://localhost:6055/API/Invitations".

Comment: Check solution from this question, this might help with your Put:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182620/put-or-delete-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-on-html-form][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182620/put-or-delete-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-on-html-form